# using unset in CakePHP MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, cakephp

I am using **Ichikawa** CakePHP MongoDB plugin. I have a problem in using `unset` in it. I have tried the command in shell:

```
 db.patents.update({}, {$unset : {"lv.2" : 1 }},{'multi':true})
 db.patents.update({},{$pull:{pid:"2"}},{'multi':true})
```

These are working fine.

But when I am converting them to CakePHP command as follows:

```
 $this->Detail->updateAll(array('$unset'=>array('lv.2'=>1,array('multi'=>true))));
```

Then it doesn't work and gives error:

```
 MongoCollection::update(): expects parameter 1 to be an array or object, boolean given
```

Can anyone help me to figure out the problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

### There are no conditions

The error message means that the query being generated is the equivalent of:

```
db.details.update(true
```

This can be confirmed by checking the [query log](https://github.com/ichikaway/cakephp-mongodb/blob/cake2.2/Model/Datasource/MongodbSource.php#L913-L915) (easy if you're using [debug kit](https://github.com/cakephp/debug_kit)).

### How is that happening

The second parameter for model [updateAll](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/lib/Cake/Model/Model.php#L2540-L2542) is missing, which means it will have the default:

```
public function updateAll($fields, $conditions = true) {
                                                 ^
    return $this->getDataSource()->update($this, $fields, null, $conditions);
}
```

Therefore in the [mongodb datasource class](https://github.com/ichikaway/cakephp-mongodb/blob/cake2.2/Model/Datasource/MongodbSource.php#L881) - the conditions passed are `true`:

```
public function updateAll(&$Model, $fields = null,  $conditions = null) {
                                                    ^
```

As a consequence, the resultant update statement has `true` as the first parameter, not an array.

### Correct syntax

The correct syntax for such a query is:

```
$this->Detail->updateAll(
    array('$unset'=>array('lv.2'=>1))
    array() # <- do not omit this
);
```

Note that it's not necessary to specify `'multi'=>true` as [the datasource does that for you](https://github.com/ichikaway/cakephp-mongodb/blob/cake2.2/Model/Datasource/MongodbSource.php#L898), especially not in the fields argument.